# Huawei phone playing sound "I am here"

Tags: huawei

My old phone Huawei G8 (RIO-L02) with Android 5.1 is only used to play music. No SIM card installed and it only has a WiFi connection. The phone frequently plays sound "I am here".

After factory resetting the phone, the sound comes back after a while (about one month). I also have already disabled the location service. The only app I installed is a music player, though I don't think it is related.

Any ideas about which apps play this sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of Huawei's Android devices known as **"Find me" function**.

For video demonstration: [Huawei P8: Find Your Phone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTWzcRd0ZBg)

The feature works by calling the name of the phone then saying "where are you?", then the device will turn on its display, turn on the flashlight, play music, and saying "I'm here".

When the phone is paired to Huawei HONOR Band, it can also be triggered by accessing the "Find my phone" feature from the band <sub>(thanks to user [Bangyou](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/134293/bangyou) for additional info)</sub>.

Depending on the model, the setting may be found on:

- Settings - Speech Awareness - Wake Up
- Settings - Smart Assistant - Voice Control - Voice Wakeup
- Settings - Smart control - Wake Up

---

Additional sources:

- [Reddit - Random "I'm here" alert](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/b5tgkl/random_im_here_alert/)
- [Reddit - Interesting "I am here" function](https://www.reddit.com/r/Honor8/comments/5sbm9u/interesting_i_am_here_function/)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is the problem, but cannot find the setting in the old Huawei phone.

Comment: @Bangyou I'm afraid I can't help further without having the same model on hand, sorry... perhaps there are 3rd-party that may reveal this setting on old model, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Very appreciate it for your help. You give me the right direction. I will try to figure out which app cause the sound. It sound the specific song (keywords) cause it.

Comment: Figure out the source of sound. It is coming from the Honer Band. My kid accidentally click "find my phone".

Comment: @Bangyou thanks for letting me know about the HONOR Band, I've added to the answer.